# How to count the number of words that contain at least 3 vowels

Tags: c, function, printing, count

I was wondering if I could ask for some help. I am writing a program in C that writes out the number of characters, words, and vowels are in the string(with a few added print statements). I am trying to figure out how to write a code that loops through the string and counts the number of words that contain at least 3 vowels. I feel as if this is a very easy code to write, but it's always the easiest things that seem to elude me. Any help?

**Also:** Being new to C, how can I get the same results while using the function `int vowel_count(char my_sen[])` instead of using the code within my main?

If that's a tad confusing I mean since my main already contains code to count the number of vowels within my input, how can I somewhat transfer said code into this function and still call upon it in main?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#define SENTENCE 256


int main(void){

char my_sen[SENTENCE], *s; //String that containts at most 256 as well as a pointer
int words = 1, count = 0,vowel_word = 0; //Integer variables being defined
int i,vowel = 0, length;  //More definitions
printf("Enter a sentence: ");//Input sentence
gets(my_sen);//Receives and processes input
length = strlen(my_sen); //Stores the length of the input within length

for(i=0;my_sen[i] != '\0'; i++){
    if(my_sen[i]=='a' || my_sen[i]=='e' || my_sen[i]=='i' || my_sen[i]=='o' || my_sen[i]=='u' || //Loop that states if the input contains any of the following
       my_sen[i]=='A' || my_sen[i]=='E' || my_sen[i]=='I' || my_sen[i]=='O' || my_sen[i]=='U')   //characters(in this case, vowels), then it shall be
       {                                                                                         //stored to be later printed
           vowel++;
       }


    if(my_sen[i]==' ' || my_sen[i]=='!' || my_sen[i]=='.' || my_sen[i]==',' || my_sen[i]==';' || //Similar to the vowel loop, but this time
        my_sen[i]=='?')                                                                          //if the following characters are scanned within the input
        {                                                                                        //then the length of the characters within the input is
            length--;                                                                            //subtracted

                    }

}


for(s = my_sen; *s != '\0'; s++){ //Loop that stores the number of words typed after
    if(*s == ' '){                //each following space
    count++;
}
}


printf("The sentence entered is %u characters long.\n", length); //Simply prints the number of characters within the input
printf("Number of words in the sentence: %d\n", count + 1); // Adding 1 to t[he count to keep track of the last word
printf("Average length of a word in the input: %d\n", length/count);//Prints the average length of words in the input
printf("Total Number of Vowels: %d\n", vowel);//Prints the number of vowels in the input
printf("Average number of vowels: %d\n", vowel/count);//Prints the average number of vowels within the input
printf("Number of words that contain at least 3 vowels: %d\n", vowel_word);//Prints number of words that contain at least 3 vowels
return 0;
}
```

Comment: The condition in your first `if`-statement would probably be more readable if you created a function similar to the ctype `is*` function, to check for vowels. Same for the second `if` statement

Answer (score 2):

It's not much of a problem.

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int vowel_count(char my_sen[])
{
  int wcount = 0; // number of words with 3+ vowel chars
  int vcount = 0; // current number of vowel chars in the current word
  int i = 0; // index into the string
  int ch;
  while ((ch = my_sen[i++]) != '\0')
  {
    if (isspace(ch) || !isalpha(ch))
    {
      // ch is not an alphabetical char, which can happen either
      // before a word or after a word.
      // If it's after a word, the running vowel count can be >= 3
      // and we need to count this word in.
      wcount += vcount >= 3; // add 1 to wcount if vcount >= 3
      vcount = 0; // reset the running vowel counter
      continue; // skip spaces and non-alphabetical chars
    }
    if (strchr("aeiouAEIOU", ch) != NULL) // if ch is one of these
    {
      ++vcount; // count vowels
    }
  }
  // If my_sen[] ends with an alphabetical char,
  // which belongs to the last word, we haven't yet
  // had a chance to process its vcount. We only
  // do that in the above code when seeing a non-
  // alphabetical char following a word, but the
  // loop body doesn't execute for the final ch='\0'.
  wcount += vcount >= 3; // add 1 to wcount if vcount >= 3
  return wcount;
}

int main(void)
{
  char sen[] = "CONSTITUTION: We the People of the United States...";
  printf("# of words with 3+ vowels in \"%s\" is %d", sen, vowel_count(sen));
  return 0;
}
```

Output ([ideone](http://ideone.com/qFB9S)):

```
# of words with 3+ vowels in "CONSTITUTION: We the People of the United States..." is 3
```

Btw, you can alter this function to count all things you need. It already finds where words begin and end and so, simple word counting is easy to implement. And word length, too. And so on.

Comment: Thank you very much for this, I especially appreciate the comments included so that I could learn from what you wrote. Again, greatly appreciated and thank you for the insight.

Comment: You're welcome. Btw `if (isspace(ch) || !isalpha(ch))` can be reduced to simply `if (!isalpha(ch))`.

Answer (score 1):

1) Get the string,

2) use strtok () to get each words seperated by space.

3) Loop through each string by char by char to check if it is vowel.

Answer (score 0):

Please check below code

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>

    int count_vowels(char []);
    int check_vowel(char);

    main()
    {
      char array[100];
      printf("Enter a string\n");
      gets(array);
      char seps[] = " ";
      char* token;
      int input[5];
      int i = 0;
      int c = 0;
      int count = 0;

      token = strtok (array, seps);
      while (token != NULL)
      {
         c = 0;
         c = count_vowels(token);
         if (c >= 3) {
            count++;
         }
         token = strtok (NULL, seps);
       }
       printf("Number of words that contain atleast 3 vowels : %d\n", count);
       return 0;
    }

    int count_vowels(char a[])
    {
       int count = 0, c = 0, flag;
       char d;

       do
       {   
          d = a[c];

          flag = check_vowel(d);

          if ( flag == 1 )
             count++;

          c++;
       }while( d != '\0' );

       return count;
    }

    int check_vowel(char a)
    {
       if ( a >= 'A' && a <= 'Z' )
          a = a + 'a' - 'A';   /* Converting to lower case */

       if ( a == 'a' || a == 'e' || a == 'i' || a == 'o' || a == 'u')
          return 1;

       return 0;
    }
```